# how to open a confirmation dialog window with Jquery UI through a click in a botton

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been reading some post and the Jquery UI Documentation in order to create a dialog window with Jquery UI after a button click, but till now I don't understand clear how is this working, because I tryed everything in my case and is not running. Here is what I have, can be somebody so kind and explain me what I am doing wrong?

```
<button type='button' id='btn_reset'style='display:block;'>Reset</button>

<div id="warnungdialog" title="Warnung" style="display:none;">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;">
        </span>Was wird passiert?</p>
</div>
```

This is what I have in the Jquery side

```
$(btn_reset).on('click', function() {

    $("#warnungdialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 350,
        height: 'auto',
        buttons: {
            Weiter: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Abbrechen: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $(btn_reset).button();
    $(btn_reset).click(function() {
        $('#warnungdialog').dialog('open');
    });

});
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
      $("#warnungdialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                Weiter: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Abbrechen: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
      $('#btn_reset').button();
      $('#btn_reset').click(function() {
         $('#warnungdialog').dialog('open');
      }); 
 });
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/0rypnw0j/2/).

Comment: No reaction from the click of the button, looks like dissable

Comment: Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/0rypnw0j/3/) as per your HTML provided!

Comment: Upss THX @Deepak Biswal was a syntax error :) I was to blind to find it! :)

Comment: Great :). Sometimes that happened!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code doesn't work because, the dialog declaration is done only when you click on button. The dialog declaration must be done before click event.
like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// here dialog declaration
$("#warnungdialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 350,
    height: 'auto',
    buttons: {
        Weiter: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Abbrechen: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
 });

 //here click event on button
    $("#btn_reset").bind("click",function(){
    $('#warnungdialog').dialog('open');
 });
 });
```

Comment: Hi Fender! Yes, I call this function inside the .ready function of the document of course. But I don't understand why is not working.

Comment: I think that you must put the dialog declaration out of "$(btn_reset).on('click', function() {}))"

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(btn_reset).button();
$(btn_reset).on('click', function() {

    $("#warnungdialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 350,
        height: 'auto',
        buttons: {
            Weiter: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Abbrechen: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

        $('#warnungdialog').dialog('open');

});
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qj6h7w2L/